# Do 午前 / 午後 change depending on minutes

Tags: time

午前0-12 goes from 00:00 to 12:00 in 24h time. Do minutes affect 午前 / 午後? Is 12:30 in 24h time still 午前１２時３０分 or does it change to 午後 thanks to the minutes going over?

Comment: 午前 means A.M., 午後 means P.M. So 12:30 a.m. is...

Comment: No, that'd be trying to coerce it into English and Japanese is not English. 12:00 in 24h is 12p.m., but 午前１２時.

Comment: Aha, now I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The most *technically correct* answer would be... both 午前１２時３０分 and 午後１２時３０分 are nonexistent. Because if you apply 12-hour notation rigidly, the time range only varies from 0:00 to 12:00 (whether the end is included or not is still debatable). Hence the value `12:30 a.m/p.m` are simply not allowed.

That said, in daily life we could understand it by considering whether the time belongs to morning (= before noon) or afternoon. In this sense, 12:30 in 24-hour notation would be 午後１２時３０分, if you have to use the number 12:30.

---

As I see from your comment, your concern is related to the controversy about whether noon/midnight should have AM or PM. Basically [it depends on definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight), but at any rate, the ambiguity only involves the very moment 12:00 AM/PM. If the time should go past noon or midnight by a single tick, it'll automatically fall under either AM or PM.

Comment: Nah, I'm only interested in japanese 午前 / 午後 use which seems much more logical than a.m. / p.m. For example it doesn't illogicaly (IMO) jump from 11:59am to 12:00pm in a single minute and that is much simplier. Ok, I get it that it is better to use 午後0:00. But, if I mention午前12:30, will any Japanese person automatically understand it as "count 12 hours + 30 minutes from the midnight"? That's seems like natural continuation of original simple idea.

Comment: Well... if you say "any", I don't deny, but not "many". Of course, even if whoever doesn't automatically understand it, enough context will make it kind of misunderstanding-free. But in the first place, if you understand the word 午前 (as well as a.m.), it means "before noon" and not "from the midnight".

Answer (score 1):

**Legal Answer**: 12:00 in 24h can be *only* written as 午前12時, <s>and therefore 12:30 in 24h *might* be 午前12時30分</s>, because [it's defined so](http://law.e-gov.go.jp/htmldata/M05/M05SE337.html) by an ancient Japanese law (in 1872), which somehow seems to be still in effect. There is no such thing as officially-defined 午後0時. (**EDIT**: As @broccoriforest says, perhaps the more accurate way to describe this situation is: "Time notation between 12:00 and 13:00 has never been officially defined in the history of Japan"...)

**Practical Answer**: Forget the legal answer. 午前12時 itself is a confusing expression which should be avoided in most cases. Never say, for example, 午前12時30分 because it's very, very confusing. Let's not try to figure out its meaning seriously. Instead, always use 午前0時 (midnight) or 午後0時 (noon) which are unambiguous and used widely on TV, digital clocks, etc., and it I think is consistent with the common English clock system. 12:30 in 24h should be written as **午後0時30分**, or 12時30分 without 午前 or 午後.

Sources:

- [午前１２時？ 午後０時？](http://jjy.nict.go.jp/QandA/FAQ/12am-or-0pm-J.html) by National Institute of Information and Communications Technology
- [正午は午前12時？それとも、午後12時？](http://www.nao.ac.jp/faq/a0401.html) by National Astronomical Observatory of Japan
- [真夜中と正午の時刻表現](https://ja.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E5%8D%88%E5%89%8D%E3%81%A8%E5%8D%88%E5%BE%8C&oldid=44423281#.E7.9C.9F.E5.A4.9C.E4.B8.AD.E3.81.A8.E6.AD.A3.E5.8D.88.E3.81.AE.E6.99.82.E5.88.BB.E8.A1.A8.E7.8F.BE)

Comment: BTW, 0時 is pronounced as れいじ, right?

Comment: ちなみに太政官布告は「午刻ヨリ子刻迄ヲ十二時ニ分チ午後幾時ト称候」なのに時刻表に記載がないので、12:00から13:00の名称については完全にundefinedなんですよね…

Comment: Usually it's れいじ, but I think I sometimes here ぜろじ, too. Technical jargon, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

In normal spoken japanese people often refer to 朝の１０時半 or 夜の２時, or something along that vein. (or just 今朝、or ２時から) 午後 or 午前 is quite formal but commonly heard in news broadcasts.